# Failed to connect to SQL Server from C# desktop application

Tags: c#, sql-server

Failed to connect to SQL Server from C# desktop application when running it from msi file however while executing program from Visual Studio, it runs perfectly.

I used VS 2017, SQL Server 2019 Express

This is my connection string:

```
Data Source="+ Properties.Settings.Default.serverName + ";Initial Catalog=sales;Integrated Security = true
```

Comment: data source = .\sqlexpress

Comment: Integrated security means you use the current user account. You as developer probably have access, but does the person installing that msi?

Comment: Well - is SQL Server Express installed locally on that other machine you're running your code on? SQL Server EXpress is a **server-based** install - it's not "embedded" inside your VS code ...

Comment: What exactly does "failed to connect" mean? We can't read your mind or see your screen.

Comment: Have a look at [SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/)

Comment: MSI is an installer.  You do not install a MDF file that is attached to A SQL Server.  Your connection string is for a Database that is installed on a SQL Server (not a localDb). You have an issue with credentials when from the machine you are installing the application the user does not have access to the database that is attached to the SQL Server.  You are using Integrated Security which means the credentials are the user credentials.  So the user has to have an account that is recognized by both the local and remote machine.  Start by using SQL Server Management Studio to get user access.

Comment: this is my connection string:     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= .\SQLEXPRESS ; Initial Catalog = sales; USER ID = sa ; Password = 1234 ");

Comment: i can login from sql server with this user & pass sucessfully

Comment: i added rules with ports to firewall ,services are runnig and i'm running the program on the same pc